# Program running on simulator but not on FPGA

Tags: riscv

I'm a bit newbie with RISCV processor and this is really anoying me

I've created a .C program for RISCV using the tutorial here http://riscv.org/download.html#tab_tools at "Testing Your Toolchain".

If I use in my computer

```
spike pk myhello
```

I get "Hello world!" as expected but if I run it on mi FPGA using this command

```
./fesvr-zynq pk myhello
```

I get

```
z  0000000000000000 ra 0000000000010030 s0 ffffffffffffffc0
s1 0000000000015290 s2 0000000000000000 s3 0000000000014b60 
s4 0000000000014b60 s5 0000000000000000 s6 0000000000000000
s7 0000000000000000 s8 0000000000000000 s9 0000000000010258
sA 0000000000000000 sB 0000000000000000 sp 000000000ff7fb40 
tp 0000000000000000 v0 0000000000000000 v1 0000000000000000 
a0 0000000000000000 a1 0000000000000000 a2 0000000000000000 
a3 0000000000000000 a4 0000000000000000 a5 0000000000000000 
a6 0000000000000000 a7 0000000000000000 t0 0000000000000000
t1 0000000000000000 t2 0000000000000000 t3 0000000000000000 
t4 0000000000000000 t5 0000000000000000 sr 00000000a00000e9 
pc 0000000000010448 va 000007fffffffff0 insn ffffffff
User store segfault @ 0x000007fffffffff0
```

Instead getting "hello world!" like the included example in the precompiled-image at SDCARD.
I've tried to boot linux but I can't send my program to the FPGA when the OS is launched.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you try copying the newer version of pk from your computer over to the FPGA and using that? Were you able to boot linux on the rocket core on the FPGA?

Comment: First of al,l sorry for not answering before, but I've been outside the country and I couldn't read the answer.
I'm going to try copying the new pk. I was able to boot linux on rocket core on the FPGA but I'm not able to copy anything to the booted linux.
Thank you for answering

Comment: Have you tried copying things into the linux disk image, as described by the README (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools)?

Comment: @user2548417 thank you for your help. After copying and booting with the new pk everything went fine.
About copying yes, now I can put my program inside my "mount" folder, but I can't do it with scp command when linux kernel is launched.

Comment: Correct, with the simple busy-box disk image you cannot copy files in and out with scp. Wheh riscv-poky is updated, you will probably be able to use that to scp files in and out.

Comment: Ok  user2548418, I'll keep an eye at the project.
I'm going to mark the question as answered. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by user2548418, updating "pk" package solved the problem (and creating again the image with it inside). 
Copying files with scp when linux kernel is booted is not currently available, but they can be loaded into the system following the instructions at *"Creating a Root Disk Image"* in [RISCV tools](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools#linuxman), copying the files into the folders created by mkdir.